# $K/k$ field extension, $[K:k]=n,f(x)\in k[x]$ irreducible over $k$ with degree $m$, and $f$ has a root in $K\implies m$ divides $n$

Tags: extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Let $K/k$ a field extension, with $[K:k]=n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $f(x)\in k[x]$, with $\deg (f)=m$. I need to show that if $f$ has a root $\alpha\in K$, so $m|n$.

I know that in $K[x]$ we can write $f(x)=(x-\alpha)g(x)$, where $g(x)\in k[x]$, but this implies $\deg(g)=m-1$. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\alpha\in K$ is this root, then $k(\alpha)$ is an intermediate field between $k$ and $K$. This implies that
$$
[K:k]=[K:k(\alpha)]\cdot [k(\alpha):k]\\
n=[K:k(\alpha)]\cdot m
$$

Comment: That was simple... thank you!
Just one more question: Is the reciprocal valid? I mean, if $m|n\implies f$ has a root in $K$?

Comment: @MateusRocha No, unfortunately. There are way too many possible roots that $f$ could have for us to guarantee that $K$ contains any of them. The only exception is if $k$ (and $K$) is a finite field.